# Stop process from with in eclipse

Tags: android

Android 2.3.3
Eclipse Indigo with `ADT` Plugin 14

I am using Eclipse Indigo with `ADT Plugin 14`. I am running the application in mobile not in the emulator.

My question is, is there a way to stop the process from within the eclipse, so that when there is a force close or when the logic is flawed and the control enters an infinite loop, we get to see where the problem lies.

Right now, when the control enters an infinite loop, it's hard to analyze where the problem is, because i have to go to `setting->applications->manage applications->search` for the app, then say force stop. By this time, the control must have looped atleast a hundred times and logcat is all the same.

If i could stop it from eclipse, when i know there is an infinite loop coming, i would just stop it and i would have a very decent chance of finding where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Go To DDMS in Eclipse, then Devices ----> Select your running Emulator ----> Select the process (I mean your package name)---> Click on the stop button on the top of Devices Tab.

Be Sure that above process works only for Emulators and not with the devices. You don't have control over real time device through DDMS.